# How can I get the accurate date and time in flutter app in offline mode, regardless of the device clock settings?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I know the network based solutions like server time, and NTP solutions. But, my app users will be offline for days in this particular use case and I want to take their attendance on offline places.

I have tried the `ntp` package in flutter, but it requires internet connection.

Comment: `DateTime.now()` but even then, you wouldn't be able to get an accurate time if the device clock is not accurate? It would just give you the current device time.

Comment: You expect your phone to use some sort of psychic powers to get the time of day when it can't communicate on the internet?

Comment: I take it back.  Consider GPS time, which might be available on your devices: https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Position/timestamp.html

Comment: If there is no network then you can't get time from the network. If people have put their clock forward you can't really detect it.

Comment: Yes, I guess there's no solution to it.

Comment: I managed to store the server time during the last online state and use it through somehow. Still, not reliable but, no other options. thanks guys. for your efforts.